# rich content editor similar to weebly page editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, interface, wysiwyg

does anyone know of a nice javascript (preferably jquery) library that allows you to drag, drop and edit in place, in a similar manner to the weebly content editor?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've been searching for something similar for a long time. Here's a compilation of the best I've found so far (apart from the obvious ones like TinyMCE, FCK Editor, NicEdit, MarkItUp! etc..)

- Rich Text Editor Framework for React https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/
- 'Medium'-like Editor http://daviferreira.github.io/medium-editor/
- WYSIHTML5 Editor http://xing.github.io/wysihtml5/
- Sir Trevor JS - easily extensible, 'blocks' concept http://madebymany.github.io/sir-trevor-js/example.html
- uEditor - very minimal http://www.upian.com/upiansource/ueditor/demo/custom.html
- Fresh Editor - minimal and light weight http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/140543/FresherEditor/demo.html
- Hallo.js - Similar to medium's editor http://hallojs.org/
- Proper - HTML5 semantic text editor http://quasipartikel.at/proper/
- Aloha Editor - great looking, free, full-page editor with good features http://www.aloha-editor.org/demos/3col/
- **QuillJS** - A powerful, extensible RTE https://quilljs.com/

Paid:

- **Froala** - Feature rich and highly extensible https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor
- Redactor - Feature rich, but it's not free for commercial use - http://imperavi.com/redactor/

(updated 20 Oct 2017)

Comment: +1 for the list. _WYSIHTML5 Editor_ looks nice but no commit since Nov'12. _Proper_ Similar is the case with Proper.

Comment: woofmark http://bevacqua.github.io/woofmark/ for Markdown & WYSIWYG

Comment: Draft.js looks very promising https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/

Comment: @DeepakThomas definitely! I have been struggling with sir trevor for a while, but looking at draft-js - that looks like a whole new level of crazy awesomness!

Comment: deepak any chance you can add a link to ASP with any of your libs listed

Answer (score 14):

So, almost four years after the original question, people are still searching.

I've been researching something similar for a couple of days now. We need a drag & drop editor for inclusion in an open source project. It needs to be a truly drag & drop site builder, not just a (fancy) text editor.
These are some of the editors that look promising. Some of these may have been mentioned before. Not all are free or open source.

- Contentbuilder.js: http://innovastudio.com/content-builder.aspx
- Odoo website builder: https://www.odoo.com/page/website-builder
- Ace/Cloud 9: http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about
- Pencil: http://pencil.evolus.vn/
- Redactor: http://imperavi.com/redactor/
- Mercury: https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury
- Impress Pages: https://www.impresspages.org/

Comment: the odoo editor is based on cke, for the [next version](http://runbot.odoo.com/runbot/1/master) it has been changed to a patched [summernote](http://summernote.org/#/) (the improvements are being submitted to summernote)

Comment: ok cool, didn't know that actually.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same concern a year ago and doing some research I found impresspages CSM give it a try. it is amazing. It's written in PHP and usus jquery to provide drag and drop for edit in place functionality. current version 2.6 and it's Open Source GNU GPL v3.0 or MIT license.

[Impresspages CMS](http://impresspages.org)

Answer (score 0):

I use [tinymce rich text editor](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) with jQuery and i am able to edit in place, drag and drop.

Comment: i am familiar with tinymce but i'm afraid it's lightyears away from weebly

Comment: tinymce is easy to use out of the box, and there are so many features you are able to use (they only need to be configured), you may even add own plugins to add more functionality to your editor. and the best thing is, it does you cost nothing

Comment: i completely understand, and tinymce is a fine rich text editor, but i'm looking for something more, and the weebly page editor is that something, it's not just about editing text, it's also very much about layout.